# Selecting lowest values in from attribute table in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, sorting

I am trying to select the lowest value from an attribute table within model builder. I have used the Sort tool to sort the values in ascending order but when I add the Select tool and go to enter an expression there is no value selectable. From my understanding, the Sort tool assigns an FID to each value with the lowest value being 1 in which I could use the Select tool and enter the expression: "FID = 1" to get my desired output.

I am relatively new to ModelBuilder.

Any suggestions on how to work through this?

[image: PDFTable_3 is the sorted field.]

Current Model[image]

Comment: To do this I would use Summary Statistics to create a table whose first row can be read by the Model Only tool available for that purpose. I’ll need to look up the name of that tool but in the meantime I think there is an earlier Q&A about this.

Comment: @PolyGeo I think the tool you're looking for is Get Field Value http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/get-field-value.htm which returns the value of a field in a table or feature class for the first row only. The workflow would be to use summary statistics to create a table with the minimum of all your values and no case field, which will result in a table with only one row then grab that min value from the table and use that in a select by attributes.

Comment: That’s the one @MichaelStimson